Best compatibility practices for developing on and deploying Docker container to cloud
Full disclosure, I'm a beginner to the world of Docker. Here's hoping my question makes sense.
I currently do all of my development on an M2 MacBook. As you might know, these computers have CPUs that are built on the ARM architecture. I've recently began trying to integrate docker into my development workflows and after doing a bit of research online, I've come to realize that not all docker images ship with an ARM compatible version. This limits the docker images that I'm able to pull and use. And so we arrive at...
Question 1: Given that the machine I use for development is ARM, is there a way to ensure my code runs on machines with different CPU architectures? The solutions I know of so far are:

Use Docker emulator, however I've heard this is not considered best practice.
Get a new machine using my desired CPU architecture, however I'm poor and don't want to do this

Now suppose I'm done with the development and now want to host the containers on the cloud. It would stand to reason that given that my Docker containers are based on ARM images, I would have to deploy to an ARM based server in order to be fully confident that my code will run and I won't run into any compatibility issues. However I don't know of many cloud providers that allow you to choose the CPU architecture your code runs on, since this might severely limit their ability to flexibly allocate resources. And so we arrive at...
Question 2: Is my reasoning sound, or can I really just deploy my code blindly? If my reasoning is sound, how do you get around this?
In other words are there cloud providers that let you specify this stuff? Or are there best practices for deployment that allow you to deploy successfully while being CPU architecture agnostic?
